# How to apply a docx footer available in last page to all pages using python-docx?

Tags: python, openxml, python-docx

I am trying to change the page orientation to landscape using Quarto when generating docx (based on [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73784720/changing-page-orientation-in-word-using-quarto/73787848#comment135098893_73787848)). Although it changes the orientation, the footer is misplaced.

In the document which is generated by quarto (see screenshot), there is a footer in page 5 but the same footer is missed in all other pages. Also, one can notice there are arbitrary number of sections. How can I make that footer reflect in all pages (including dynamic page numbers)?

[image: see screenshot]

Below is the code I tried,

```
from docx import Document
document = Document(r"C:\dev\poetry-demo\poetry_demo\test.docx")
n_sections = len(document.sections)
document.sections[0].footer = document.sections[n_sections].footer
# Attribute error
```

Note: Quarto works based on template and I can extract the `footer.xml` from it. Hence, I am okay if one can apply that `ooxml` for all sections.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't assign the section 3 footer on other section because I was getting malformed word content while opening.

However, below code worked.

```
footer_xml = """
<w:ftr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
<w:p>
<w:r>
<w:t>This is a custom footer.</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:ftr>
"""

document = Document('test.docx')
sections = document.sections
for section in sections:
    section.footer._definition._element = parse_xml(footer_xml) #sections[-1].footer._definition._element
document.save('test1.docx')
```